# How do I share a folder between two ubuntu 14.04 machine and access it using terminal?

Tags: 14.04

I am using two Ubuntu 14.04 machine on same network, say A and B. I have a folder in A which i need to share with B. I connected A with B using 'Connect to Server' option. Post which i was able to access all files and folders present on machine A. But am not able to access the same through terminal.

Please suggest a way to achieve accessing of remote folder using terminal between two Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to install `openssh-server` on both `pc`. Then you can log fro `A` to `B` and vice versa from terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Command for logging from `A` to `B` wil be:

```
ssh user_on_B@ip_address_of_B
```

Also you can user `sftp` to exchange files between hosts.

```
From A

sftp user_from_B@ip_address_of_B
```

then, when you are logged to `B`

```
get file_name
```

and file will be transferred to `A`

More about `sftp` you have [here](https://www.tecmint.com/sftp-command-examples/)

Or you can use `mc`

```
 sudo apt install mc
```

then in terminal open `mc`
[image]

go to `menu` then `richt` of `left` and from `menu` add `sftp`[image]

Enter `user_of_B@ip_of_B` hit enter. Enter password and you will have files
from `A` in one panel and files of `B` in second panel.